# Homebrew on Mac OSX Mountain Lion - can't seem to install git

Tags: git, macos, homebrew

I downloaded and installed homebrew for Mac OSX Mountain

```
admins-Mac-mini:~ admin$ brew install git
You must: brew install git
You must: brew install git
You must: brew install git
You must: brew install git
Error: Git is unavilable
Error: Failure while executing: /usr/local/bin/brew tap homebrew/core -q
```

What is the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the OS X developer tools installed?

Comment: do you mean the command line tools?

Comment: Yes. I think (but Mountain Lion is so long ago) that you need them to install the system-version of Git (should be installed as `/usr/bin/git`), which may be required to bootstrap Homebrew.

Comment: Yeah i know Mountain Lion is old but i need it for a specific reason. Any chance you could elaborate more on the process? I'm just coming from a Windows background

Comment: Can you add the output of `brew doctor` to your question?

Comment: The output is the exact same thing as described in my original post.

Comment: Did you install the command line tools? Also, does `/usr/bin/git` exist? (`ls -al /usr/bin/git`). If not, you may have to install git [manually](https://git-scm.com/) first (because Homebrew depends on it).

Comment: I did install the command line tools and /usr/bin/git exists, that's the weird thing about it

Comment: Last thing that I can think of: try running `sudo brew install git` (`sudo` runs the command as root/administrator).

Comment: Maybe ```sudo ln -s /usr/bin/git /usr/local/bin/git```? :/

Comment: I had the same issue, @BlueSpaceCanary's tip about linking /usr/local/bin/git is correct